# How to randomly pick value from a list in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Suppose I have a list of Robot class [List< Robot> myList=new List< Robot>()]. Each Robot has a name and id depending on its colour. Now randomly pick values from the list and give an output of how many Robots of each colour are there on your list.
(N.B. Consider you have only 3 colored Robot[Yellow,green, red])

my code:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        List<Robot> myList = new List<Robot>();
        List<string> robotList = new List<string>();
        robotList.Add("yellow");
        robotList.Add("green");
        robotList.Add("red");

        int someNum = Random.Range(0, robotList.Count);
        string robotNumber = robotList[someNum];
        robotList.RemoveAt(someNum);
        Robot robot;
        int id = 0;
        robot = new Robot(robotNumber, id);
        Debug.Log(robot);
        id++;
    }
}

public class Robot
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
    public Robot(string name, int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

but this not work maybe.. actually I don't understand what actually my output is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure to really understand what you're asking for: if it's only about the meaning of the `Debug.Log(robot);` output, check for @Smartis answer as it answers it perfectly :)

Otherwise, I feel like you wanted to populate a `List<Robot>` with random picked names. In this case you need to use a loop: `Start()` method is only called once on start (as its name suggest). If you need to populate a list with random picked colors/names and then display how many of each colors/names are in the list you can do it as follow:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Start()
    {
        List<Robot> robotsList = new List<Robot>();
        List<string> namesList = new List<string>();
        namesList.Add("yellow");
        namesList.Add("green");
        namesList.Add("red");

        PopulateRobotsList();
        DisplayRobotsListContent();
    }

    private void PopulateRobotsList()
    {
        for(int id = 0; id < 100; id++)
        {
            string robotName = namesList[Random.Range(0, namesList.Count)];
            robotsList.Add(new Robot(robotName, id));
            //Debug.Log(robotsList[robotsList.Count - 1]);
        }
    }

    private void DisplayRobotsListContent()
    {
        int[] robotsNamesCount = new int[namesList.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < robotsList.Count; i++)
        {
            robotsNamesCount[namesList.IndexOf(robotsList[i].name)] += 1;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < namesList.Count; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Robot(s) named \"" + namesList[i] + "\" : " + robotsNamesCount[i]);
        }
    }
}

public class Robot
{
    public string name;
    public int id;
    public Robot(string name, int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Please note I changed some variable names as I found it really hard to understand with the one you provided (ex: `robotsList` to store the potential colors/names of the robots is a weird choice of name :) ).

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: robotsNamesCount[namesList.IndexOf(robotsList[i])] += 1;
some error shown

Comment: My bad there was a typo. Correct line is `robotsNamesCount[namesList.IndexOf(robotsList[i].name)] += 1;`.

Answer (score 3):

Your random pick works fine *(even when your code is a little bit confusing)*. I guess your problem is, you don't understand the output of `Debug.Log(robot);`.

> actually I don't understand what actually my output is... **- OP**

### What does `Debug.Log()` print?

According to the [Unity3D Documentation for this function](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) will converted the given object to be to string representation for display. This means simply the return value of `ToString()` method on your Object will printed.

So let's have look at the `Object.ToString()` method and it's behavior in the [MSDN Documentatio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)n.

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type. **- MSDN**

So, your output in the Unity Log will be **the Type Definition** of your object.

### Now, how to get useful information?

Just override the default `ToString()` method of your `Robot` class to something like this:

```
public class Robot
{
    public string name;
    public int id;

    public Robot(string name, int id)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    // Here start's the magic!
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Robot -> Id:'{0}' Name:'{1}'", id, name);
    }
}
```